# Node js RESTFUL API with Firebase as database

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter

We have a graduation project and we decided make an app with flutter.We thought we can use firebase authentication and database storage for data that come from node js api but I could not find any example of it. I saw flutter apps with MongoDB/Node and Express js api. Is that possible to make an app  with using firebase and API has been made by node js?

Comment: You can create Node.js functions using Firebase Functions and build your RESTful API, there are plenty of resources if you search for it. Although you can consume any RESTful endpoints from Flutter, if you plan to use Firebase Authentication, it is very easy with Firebase Functions, for example you have access to custom claims from Firebase Functions set using Firebase Authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with installing firebase to your project

```
npm install firebase
```

Here is an example of code provided by Google

```
// Get a database reference to our posts
 const db = getDatabase();
 const ref = db.ref('server/saving-data/fireblog/posts');

 // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
 ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
 }, (errorObject) => {
     console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.name);
 });
```

I made it in one of my projects so recommend you read the docs

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

### Update

So you need to set up your firebase project
Follow instruction here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Now second thing is how to add firebase to you node.js express project

```
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase/app");
const { getDatabase, ref, set, onValue } = require("firebase/database");


// Set the configuration for your app
// TODO: Replace with your project's config object
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.YOUR_VALUE_FROM_DOT_ENV_FILE,
    authDomain: process.env.YOUR_VALUE_FROM_DOT_ENV_FILE,
    databaseURL: process.env.YOUR_VALUE_FROM_DOT_ENV_FILE,
    projectId: process.env.YOUR_VALUE_FROM_DOT_ENV_FILE,
    storageBucket: process.env.YOUR_VALUE_FROM_DOT_ENV_FILE,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.YOUR_VALUE_FROM_DOT_ENV_FILE,
    appId: process.env.YOUR_VALUE_FROM_DOT_ENV_FILE

};
const firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Get a reference to the database service
const database = getDatabase(firebase);
```

**All this things you will get from firebase account**

Now Express section here is part of example

```
app.post('/items', (req, res) => {
   const postData = req.body;
   const db = getDatabase();
   const ephemeralId = Date.now().toString();
   set(ref(db, 'items/' + ephemeralId), postData).then(_r => {
       res.status(201).send({
           success: true,
           insertedId: ephemeralId,
       });
    }).catch(err => {
       res.status(420).send(err);
    });

   });
```

And as I promised here is full code on git
https://github.com/labadze/node-express-firebase-database-api/tree/master

Comment: Thank you for answer. I want to ask something about it if it is ok. I search about rest api with firebase but I do not know if I develop an api with firebase then how can i access it from a flutter project?

Comment: @GokaySendil if we are talking about web app here is documentation how to use firebase https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/firebase

Comment: Firebase gives you benefits use data without back end or you can build node restful api and use firebase as database engine and access it as normal back-end I can provide code example if needed

Comment: It would be great if you can give a code example. This is my first time asking question. I worked with flutter a lot but did nat work with API.I am new to Node js.I've just starting learning it.I saw some videos on youtube or articles about serverless api with express and firebase cloud functions. I want to make my own backend and use it in our flutter project how can i do it or can i do it ? @ArchilLabadze

Comment: @GokaySendil you can for sure, give me few minutes I’ll provide with key moments and url for GitHub if you don’t mind.

Comment: @GokaySendil one question from me, would you prefer TypeScript or common Javascript?

Comment: I am not familiar with typescript but heard it is better version of javascript If you use javascript for this time it would be great but I would like to learn typescript after learning a little bit more node js in future. If there is no big differences please use typescript thank you for everything @Archil Labadze

Comment: Sure no problem give me few minutes I’ll write things and come back with working project

Comment: @GokaySendil I updated my answer and as I promised provided code on gihub

Comment: @GokaySendil - You welcome